# ASP.NET button options.clientSubmit is set to false

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms, postback

I have a ASP.NET button which sometimes does not post back. I checked this in IE developer and found that when the button does not work `options.clientSubmit` is set to false in the function `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions()`

My button code

```
<asp:Button 
           runat="server" 
           ID="btnSubmit" 
           CssClass="button" 
           OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"  
           meta:resourcekey="btnSubmitResource1" />
```

Inside `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(options)`

```
    if (options.clientSubmit) {
    __doPostBack(options.eventTarget, options.eventArgument);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why the button sometimes works and sometimes does not? what should I do to make it work always?

Comment: Is there a question in there? I can't see one.

Comment: I did some modifications, can you see the question now?

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I'm using OnClientClick. The clientSubmit option is being hardcoded to false in the generated code: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("enroll1$btnSubmitCC", "", true, "", "", false, false));

Comment: Mine is getting a script error when I clicked submit, but only in FireFox due to an event validation exception. Still trying to figure out why, but just thought I'd share since script errors are pretty much hidden in FireFox now.

Comment: Are you using an UpdatePanel?

Comment: @rickschott yes,I am using update panel

Answer (score 3):

This may be a possibility:

Check if you have any `Validators` on the page which have not been grouped to any `ValidationGroup` and may be visible false(may be due container is visible false). This validator may be validating the control which is of no relevance under this circumstance and causing the postback to cancel saying it invalid.

If you find any, to group all the related controls, assign a `ValidationGroup` to all the corresponding `Validators` and then assign that group to your submit control(whichever causes postback). This is most common mistake I have seen..

Answer (score 2):

Try adding CausesValidation = "False" and see what happens.  I suspect you have some validation that isn't passing.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using anything to prevent repeated submission of the form?

I had exactly the same issue, the .Net validation method indicated that the form was valid, but options.clientSubmit was always false :S

The culprit turned out to be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.prevDblSubmit').preventDoubleSubmit();
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems that should be working, instead of using meta:resourcekey="btnSubmitResource1", try explicit localization. See question: [ASP.NET: explicit vs implicit localization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535797/asp-net-explicit-vs-implicit-localization/7655755#7655755)